# Is fetch inside getStaticProps and getServerSideProps the same as the native browser fetch API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I have been using Next.js for a while now, and I doubt the **fetch API** used inside `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps`.

Below I have written my understanding about `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps`:

**getStaticProps** gets called on build time and during ISR

**getServerSideProps** will get called at request time, but both don't have access to the client-side.

This is my understanding of these async functions.

So my doubt is we only write server-side code and Node.js doesn't have a native fetch API, so what fetch API is used inside `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps`? Is it the **native fetch** ? Or some **polyfill** with the name fetch?

```
async function getStaticProps(ctx){
  // Which fetch API is this, browser fetch or some polyfill with same name as 
  fetch?
  const data = fetch(.../..) // Some API
  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  }
}

  async function getServerSideProps(ctx){
  // ** Which fetch API is this, browser fetch or some polyfill with same name as 
  fetch?
  const data = fetch(.../..) // **Some API**
  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  }
}
```

Really curious to know which **fetch API** is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my doubt is we only write server-side code and node.js doesn't have a native fetch API, so what fetch API is used inside getStaticProps and getServerSideProps?

In the Node.js environment (`getStaticProps`, `getServerSideProps` and API routes) Next.js uses `node-fetch` to [polyfill the `fetch` API](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/server/node-polyfill-fetch.js).