# How to manage getServerSideProps in client side rendering Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Nextjs framework,I was reading about "server side rendering" and "client side rendering",
so we should use CSR(client side rendering) if we have "large amount of dynamic data" on the other hand we should SSR(server side rendering)
if we have "less amount of dynamic data", so i want to know that

1. If we have "large amount of dynamic data" so there should always use "server side props" ?
2. There must be "getStaticProps" for "build time" and "getServerSideProps" "run time" ? if yes then
3. Can we use "getstaticProps" and "getServerSideProps" in "CSR",in other words let suppose i have
   "large amount of data" so i decided to use "CSR" but i have to "fetch data of multiple users"
   so in this case what is right way ?

Comment: It's not depend on large or less data, it's SEO. If you dont need SEO, just stick with CSR

Comment: @iamhuynq let suppose i dont need SEO so in one of my page i want to get "data of every user" so is this possible with "CSR" ? If yes then how ?

Comment: if "data of every user" is large, you should use lazy loading or pagination to break data into smaller

Comment: @iamhuynq if "data of every use is not large" then ? is this possible with "CSR" ? If yes then how ? i am asking because if i am not wrong then if we have to request to server again and again then we must use "SSR" , am i right or wrong ?

Comment: In csr, the response of server send back have no "data of every user", it's a blank page, then user browser will fetch data from your api and "data of every user" display in page. In SSR, the response of server send back already have "data of every user" because it prefech data from api before respone to browser. So it will not have blank page but the response time will be longer than csr

Comment: @iamhuynq understand your point, but in both case we will use "Api", How browser will fetch data ? means which function/method should use ?

Comment: Browser have [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) method or you can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library

Comment: @iamhuynq Understand and if we are using "ssr" then which method should use ?

Comment: Axios run both in browser and server (nodejs environment). Fetch only run in browser, but    in nextjs, fetch gets polyfilled with node-fetch on the server-side, so its  perfectly fine to use fetch in getServerSideProps [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795872/is-fetch-inside-getstaticprops-and-getserversideprops-the-same-as-the-native-bro)

Comment: I'd recommend a read through the official docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering and https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side.